# line graph rounding off the scale values (rgraph)

Tags: javascript, rgraph

my line graph is not displaying decimal values instead it is rounding off the decimal values on y axis

```
var line1 = new RGraph.Line({
        id: 'cvs',
        data: [
            [5.85, 5.86, 5.87, 5.88, 5.89, 5.90, 5.91, 5.92, 5.93, 5.94]
        ],
        options: {
            linewidth: 1,
            backgroundGrid: false,
            title: 'X-Chart',
            colors: ['red'],
            fillstyle: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.2)',
            ymin: 5.75,
            ymax: 6,
            labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
            scale: 0.2,
            textAccessible: true
        }
    }).draw();
```

thank you

Comment: please add code snippet

Comment: var line1 = new RGraph.Line({
            id: 'cvs',
            data: [
                [5.85, 5.86, 5.87, 5.88, 5.89, 5.90, 5.91, 5.92, 5.93, 5.94]
            ],
            options: {
                linewidth: 1,
                backgroundGrid: false,
                title: 'X-Chart',
                colors: ['red'],
                fillstyle: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.2)',
                ymin: 5.75,
                ymax: 6,
                labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
                scale: 0.2,
                textAccessible: true
            }
        }).draw();

Comment: Edit your question and add this code there. It will be helpful for users to understand your question

Comment: http://www.rgraph.net/docs/line.html#labels you can use your own `scaleFormatter`

Answer (score 0):

You should add the scaleDecimals option to your configuration:

```
...
scaleDecimals: 2,
...
```

There's an example of it in a demo called **line-us-prison-population.html** and you can see that by downloading the RGraph archive here:

https://www.rgraph.net/download.html#stable